# context aware fill, and generative fill problem while removing text from image in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

I'm having trouble figuring out the cause of a (context-aware fill / generative fill) problem.

I have images with text in them. I want to remove the text.
This is the procedure I want to do to make the most accurate selection:

- select - color range (select text color)
- select - modify - expand (3px)
- selection result:
  [image]
- deselect parts of the image that have selections that are not text
- Shift-F5 (Fill) content aware - color adaptation checked - blend mode normal - opacity 100%
- sometimes this kinda works (here you can still see the contours of some of the letters):
  [image]
- sometimes it does not and leaves a faint residue of the letters, like if the letters are turned down 90% in opacity.
  [image]
  [image]
- also using photoshop beta, with generative fill on the selection I sometimes get weird  results:
  [image]

HOWEVER!!
when I use a box selection (instead of the color range selection)
[image]
I get way better results (both with generative fill, as with content aware fill)

I'm wondering what could be causing this.
[image]

Comment: I'd guess that by trying to limit the selection you're not giving it enough space to work in, so it's using only very nearby blending. tbh, I'd never dream of trying to select text that way for content-aware fill. I've always just used a marquee or rough lasso.

Comment: For removing stuff, the generative fill in the Beta works better if you make a rectangular selection, and don't add any prompts. It's just the way they seem to have designed it.  If you make a highly detailed selection, the algorithm seems to think you are trying to add something to the existing image, rather than trying to remove something.